# Upload file to server with variable path

Tags: php, yii2

I have a fileupload function that is supposed to save files in different locations depending on which form was submitted.

First of all, I have in the same view the two ActiveForms to submit a file with (different variable in the field):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['upload', 'id' => $model->id, 'mod' => 1]), 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file1')->fileInput(['style' => ''])->label(false) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Upload', ['class' => 'btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['upload', 'id' => $model->id, 'mod' => 0]), 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file2')->fileInput(['style' => ''])->label(false) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Upload', ['class' => 'btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

To my understanding, this would then put those files in the variable in the corresponding model:

```
 * @var file1
 * @var file2

 */
class X extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

     /**
     * @var UploadedFile file1 attribute
     */
    public $file1;

    /**
    * @var UploadedFile file2 attribute
    */
   public $file2;
```

with the 'action' pointing to upload, it should call the xController action:

```
public function actionUpload($id, $mod) {
      $model = new X();

          if($mod == 1){
                $model->file1 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file1');

                if($model->file1){
                    $path = 'uploads/docs1/'. $id .'/';
                    if(!is_dir($path)){
                        FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
                        $model->pwFile->saveAs($path . $model->file1->baseName . '.' . $model->file1->extension);
                    }else{
                        $files = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($path);
                        if(empty($files) || is_null($files)){
                            $model->file1->saveAs($path . $model->file1->baseName . '.' . $model->file1->extension);
                        }else{
                            foreach($files as $file){
                                unlink($file);
                            }
                            $model->file1->saveAs($path . $model->file1->baseName . '.' . $model->file1->extension);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }else{
                $model->file2 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file2');
                if($model->file2){
                    $path = 'uploads/docs2/'. $id .'/';
                    if(!is_dir($path)){
                        FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
                    }
                    $model->file->saveAs($path . $model->file2->baseName . '.' . $model->file2->extension);
                }
        }

          return $this->render('view', ['model' => $this->findModel($id)]);
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work. The upload for file1 works alright, the file gets uploaded to the server and that's it. If I use the second form however, it loads the correct url but nothing gets saved on the server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a massive amount of duplicated code, which makes it harder to debug.  I hacked away at it and I think the below is optimal.  I've also changed a few things, which should be pretty easy for you to spot.

```
public function actionUpload($id, $mod) {
    $model = new X();

    if($mod == 1) {
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file1');
        $path = 'uploads/docs1/'. $id .'/';
    } else {
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file2');
        $path = 'uploads/docs2/'. $id .'/';
    }

    if ($file->name != '') {
        if(is_dir($path)){
            $files = \yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles($path);
            foreach($files as $file){
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
        FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
        $file->saveAs($path . $file->name);
    }

    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $this->findModel($id)]);
}
```

I think this will work now, if not, give me a shout and I'll have another look.